# Where to start for workout project

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, database-design

I have learned the basics of react and redux and now I want to make a workout planner with a range of exercise lists.

However, I didn't find a good workout API that has a lot of exercises. So I was wondering how I could make my own API which would consists of the picture of the exercise,which muscle it works and a short description on how to execute it.

Is a MERN stack suitable? Where can I store the pictures and information?

I have nearly no experience on Full Stack development, only a few tutorials so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definite answer to your question.

This could be a simple Reactjs app or a more complex MERN app, depending on how you want to go about it.

The simple way would be to just create a JSON file that you can read and write from using React or even plain Javascript.

```
"id": "1",
"exercise": "Push Ups",
"imageLink": "https://image" etc...
```

The full stack way you would mainly be working on RESTful CRUD api using Node.js to create, edit, update and delete your exercises.

If you're still learning the I would suggest going full stack just for educational purposes. Maybe even add your own authentication and user levels (Admin, manager, trainer, student).